# Using append with variables jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create a script element and append the google map function there.
I'm wondering: can I use a variable in my function via the append.

```
var center = {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644};

document.createElement("script").append(
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: center,
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
);
```

Comment: Why not create a separate javascript-file with function that accepts the coordinates as a parameter and reference that in your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.append(...)` is only for a Node or a DOM string. Not for JS code.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Why aren't you calling initMap() directly?
Like this:

```js
var center = {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644};

function initMap() {
  return new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: center,
    zoom: 8
 });
 
 var map = initMap();
```

Comment: This is used in a separate file without Google API. The function of google is not defined. I'm trying to create a function through the append, to run it already on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can run script using this method. Because `append` only used for `Node`-s.

```
function runScript(func) {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.innerHtml = func.toString();
    document.head.appendChild(e);
}

runScript(function(){
    alert('okay');
});
```

You can run any js script using this method.

```
runScript(function(){
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: center,
      zoom: 8
    });
});
```